# vmlinuz and initrd strange files appeared in "/" directory

Tags: filesystem, files

I have recently noticed that four new files have appeared in my `/` directory:

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    33 Apr  9 14:07 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-34-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    33 Mar 23 19:42 initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-33-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    30 Apr  9 14:07 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-34-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    30 Mar 23 19:42 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-33-generic
```

As I have not seen them there before I was wondering what they are and why they are now there. So I was wondering if someone could explain this to me?

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have seen them before, but simply failed to notice them. If they weren't present, or were broken links, I'd be concerned.

Comment: Muru is right.  They are there.  They are links to the boot files, and should be left alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, they are [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) and, [as muru said](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612471/vmlinuz-and-initrd-strange-files-appeared-in-directory#comment861901_612471), probably they have been there all the time but you just didn't notice them.

This answer in [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2259423&p=13201002#post13201002) explains pretty well why they're there:

> Let's look at a grub config entry in /boot/grub/grub.cfg:
>
> ```
> menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menu
> entry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-blahblahblah' {
>         [...]
>         linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-28-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=blahblahblah ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
>         initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-28-generic
> }
> ```
>
> You don't need those symlinks if you always boot from this grub.cfg.
>   If you are ever manually pointing grub to a boot, 'vmlinuz' is a lot
>   easier to remember and type than '/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-28-generic' The
>   symlinks are a legacy from simpler booting times, but still
>   occasionally very handy.   You can delete the symlinks if you wish,
>   but they will be recreated the next time grub updates it's grub.cfg
>   file.
>
> Lots of stuff gets updated automatically whenever you install a new
>   kernel, including your initrd.img and grub.cfg...and those symlinks.

More info about [vmlinuz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vmlinux) and [initrd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd).

Answer (score 0):

They are soft links to file in /boot mount point

> 1 root root    33 Apr  9 14:07 initrd.img ->
>   boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-34-generic

initrd stands for Initial RAM Disk. initrd is used by kernel as temporary root file system until kernel is booted and the real root file system is mounted. It also contains necessary drivers compiled inside, which helps it to access the hard drive partitions, and other hardware.

> lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    33 Mar 23 19:42 initrd.img.old ->
>   boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-33-generic

This is old version before updating

> lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    30 Apr  9 14:07 vmlinuz ->
>   boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-34-generic

This is current kernel  you can check with "uname -r" command

> lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    30 Mar 23 19:42 vmlinuz.old ->
>   boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-33-generic

This is old version of kernel before updating to current version